# Set speed limits on Maps layer

Tags: google-roads-api

I would like to create a map with a layer, like a traffic layer, but with the speed limits of roads (route, highway,...) with the différents speed.

How can I create a layer with speed limits of all roads?

Answer (score 0):

It's practically impossible using just the Road API. You would have to create a route that makes you circle around every street. Also there limitations on how many points you can put in a route request.

My suggestion would be to gather the speed limit info from the Road API and then create a map using the [Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers) to set custom markers that indicate the speed limit on each road.